# Lisp: How to use loop named, then return-from

Tags: common-lisp

This lisp works (SBCL 1.2.15):

```
(defun roman2 ()
    (let ((x nil))
      (loop 
           (cond
             ((null x) (format t "Enter number:") (setf x (read)))
             ((> x 39) (format t "too big~%") (setf x nil))
             ((> x 9) (prin1 'x) (setf x (- x 10)) )
             ((= x 9) (prin1 'ix) (setf x 0) )
             ((> x 4) (prin1 'v) (setf x (- x 5)) )
             ((= x 4) (prin1 'iv) (setf x 0) )
             ((> x 0) (prin1 'i) (setf x (1- x)) )
             ((zerop x) (setf x nil) (terpri))
             ((< x 0) (format t "Bye.") (return))))))
```

and this doesn't

```
(defun roman2 ()
    (let ((x nil))
      (loop named rlp
           (cond
             ((null x) (format t "Enter number:") (setf x (read)))
             ((> x 39) (format t "too big~%") (setf x nil))
             ((> x 9) (prin1 'x) (setf x (- x 10)) )
             ((= x 9) (prin1 'ix) (setf x 0) )
             ((> x 4) (prin1 'v) (setf x (- x 5)) )
             ((= x 4) (prin1 'iv) (setf x 0) )
             ((> x 0) (prin1 'i) (setf x (1- x)) )
             ((zerop x) (setf x nil) (terpri))
             ((< x 0) (format t "Bye.") (return-from rlp))))))
```

with error

```
caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of (LOOP NAMED RLP ...). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to
;   intercept.
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong. It seems like if I've named my loop, I can break out with `(return-from rlp)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two forms of **[loop](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm)**. The first is simply **(loop forms...)**,which is the first one you had. The second is much more complex and uses a sophisticated language built with loop keywords to describe a loop. Once you are using **named** you're in the latter.  Try **(loop named name do (cond ...))**.